# Ionic 4 adding a menu

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

So I am new to ionic and angular, I am trying to add an ionic menu to my project, I've added it successfully and it is also working. But the thing I want to know is that, can I add the menu code in some other file? other than app.component.html ? like here I have my home page and I have one more page that is the menu page. I want to add the menu code on this "menu.component.html" page rather than the "app.component.html" page.

Comment: you can make a component and use it in other files. But First Why you want to add it into other files?

Comment: actually if i put that menu code in app.component.ts as shown in docs, it will be then available to all pages including login and registration page, which no one will want for sure. I want that menu to be appear on home page only when someone Logs In.

Comment: for that you can use Menu Controller. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu

Answer (score 0):

to Enable or Disable Menu on Any Page you can use: [Menu Controller](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu)

Example on Login page:

```
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

export class LoginPage{

constructor(private menu: MenuController) { }
   ionViewWillEnter(){
     this.disbaleMenu()
   }
  
  disbaleMenu() {
    this.menu.enable(false);       
  }    
}
```